# Visual Studio 2022 escribe dos veces el mismo carácter

Tags: visual-studio, bug

En visual studio,al escribir, en ciertas partes de mi codigo en javascript. al escribir me escribe doble
ya intente:

- reiniciar todas las configuraciones
- deshabilite todas las extensiones
- repare la instalación de vs2022
- ya actualice vs2022 hasta la ultima version disponible (01/06/2023) Version 17.6.2

aquí no pasa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero aquí si

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con VS2019 no tengo ese problema, ¿tendre que trabajar por el momento?

Comment: ¿Ya descartaste definitivamente un problema con el teclado?

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/14206

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, tengo el mismo problema, y lo solucioné seleccionando el Editor de HTML o Editor de HTML con codificación para abrir los archivos.
El problema solo aparece seleccionando el Editor HTML (formularios Web Forms)